# How to access Parent from child in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access an object's own function from a jQuery method which fails.

```
function obj(){    
    this.send = function(){
        $.get("send.php",null,function(data){
            this.success();
        }).error(function(){ this.fail(); });
    }
    this.fail = function(){
        alert("fail");
    }
}

var o = new obj();
o.send();
```

Gives this error: `TypeError: this.fail is not a function`

How to access function `fail` inside jQuery?

Comment: Why downvote this? Sure this has been asked a hundred of times and is a simple scoping issue, but still.

Comment: Also, you were calling the constructor's `.send` method (which is a syntax error), I assume you had a problem with the renaming so I fixed your code to call the instance's send method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 5, `fail`is not called by the same object, so `this`does not have the same reference, and therefore no method fail. We say that **you change context**.

The trick is to use a variable often called *`self`* or *`that`* or *`_this`*. I prefer `self`.

```
function obj(){    
    var self = this;
    this.send = function(){
        $.get("send.php",null,function(data){
            this.success();
        }).error(function(){ self.fail(); });
    }
    this.fail = function(){
        alert("fail");
    }
}
```

It should make it, and yes, javascript looks like a pity language. But once you overcome the few problems, you will love the possibilities.

Comment: `self` is actually a reference to the current document's window object and by declaring a variable with that name you're shadowing the global `self`. Not that it's a very significant thing, but worth noting that the global `self` won't be accessible inside the instance then (except by `window.self`/`window['self']` of course).

Comment: okay, so now I prefer `that` :) ; thought `self` is a better word to explain the stuff. I keep self in the code for documentation, but I won't use it. Maybe `_self`, but I intensively use the underscore library.

Comment: My codebase currently uses `self`. Luckily checking the code in strict mode with `jslint` will pick up undeclared references to a `self` object, making it harder to get into the scrape @Fabrizio describes.